# how to create group if not exist and add hosts to it dynamically

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have a special requirement to add hosts names to group when a condition satisfy ( also i need to create the group if not exist) where that group will be passed in another play,

```yaml
# check if other side os is running on this host
- set_fact:
    other_pair_host: "{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('ha', 'hb') }}"
  when: (inventory_hostname | regex_search('^.+ha.+$') )
- set_fact:
    other_pair_host: "{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('hb', 'ha') }}"
  when: (inventory_hostname | regex_search('^.+hb.+$') )
- name: check other side host is running
  set_fact:
    other_side_running: "{{ other_pair_host in groups['reachable_other_pairs'] }}"
  when: check_other_side_running == true

# if 'check_other_side_running' is set to false means we are on B side installation and we have already validated
- set_fact:
    other_side_running: true
  when: check_other_side_running == false
```

Now I need to create and the hosts too that group say 'failed_hosts'. Something like this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    host: inventory_hostname
  when: check_other_side_running == false
- group_by:
    key: "reachable_other_pairs"
```

Not sure how to do this properly.

After adding this I will use this group in another play like below

```yaml
- name: Install on failed hosts
  hosts: failed_hosts
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
```

Can someone advise on this?

Comment: See [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html)

Comment: i have tried add host but its values are replaced for every tasks

- add_host:                                                                      
    hostname: "{{other_pair_host}}"                                              
    groups: "rechable_b_switches"                                                
  when: switch_os_version != OS_version and check_other_side_running

Comment: ok: [pakzha991] => {
    "msg": [
        "b hosts ['pakzhb991']",
        "failed hosts []"
    ]
}
ok: [pakzha992] => {
    "msg": [
        "b hosts ['pakzhb991']",
        "failed hosts []"
    ]
}
ok: [pakzha993] => {
    "msg": [
        "b hosts ['pakzhb991']",
        "failed hosts []"
    ]
}